# Encrypt / Decrypt images (w/o temporary files)

Tags: ruby, image, encryption, offline

I have for example 10 images. I want them all in a single file (like gzipping them into a single file or somehow put them into a .dat file). The encryption doesn't need to be done through ruby because I just need to do that once before releasing the application.
But in my (Ruby) application I want to open the encrypted file and ONLY retrieve the image that I need to be displayed (as a Bitmap). Without first extracting it to the harddrive. So I want it loaded directly into my program.

I know that in C# for example I could load a bitmap directly from 'IO stream'. Then I would decrypt the entire package/.dat file in memory and then create a bitmap from the IO stream and then dispose the package in memory.

Are there any libraries or methods available for this? (Preferable with samples)

Note that the encryption doesn't need to be strong. Just enough to stop the common user. And my application is an offline one (has nothing to do with SSL/server-client/etc.)

Comment: How are you going to display the image? The question is whether your GUI toolkit supports rendering bitmaps from memory stream. The rest is trivial.

Comment: Right now the code for loading an image is: Bitmap.new(path). I thought that this was a standard Ruby class... So it's from the 'GUI toolkit' then... Oh no that means that I have to extend that class to be able to read such streams myself somehow?